# Python: How to determine the type of a property in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I have the following classes defined that inherits from some other classes. Goblin is a Python dependency package that I am extending from.

```
class AnnotatedVertexProperty(goblin.VertexProperty):
    notes = goblin.Property(goblin.String)
    datetime = goblin.Property(DateTime)

class KeyProperty(goblin.Property):
    def __init__(self, data_type, *, db_name=None, default=None, db_name_factory=None):
        super().__init__(data_type, default=None, db_name=None, db_name_factory=None)

class TypedVertex(goblin.Vertex):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertex_type = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
        super().__init__()

class TypedEdge(goblin.Edge):
    def __init__(self):
        self.edge_type = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
        super().__init__()

class Airport(TypedVertex):
    #label
    type = goblin.Property(goblin.String)
    airport_code = KeyProperty(goblin.String)
    airport_city = KeyProperty(goblin.String)
    airport_name = goblin.Property(goblin.String)
    airport_region = goblin.Property(goblin.String)
    airport_runways = goblin.Property(goblin.Integer)
    airport_longest_runway = goblin.Property(goblin.Integer)
    airport_elev = goblin.Property(goblin.Integer)
    airport_country = goblin.Property(goblin.String)
    airport_lat = goblin.Property(goblin.Float)
    airport_long = goblin.Property(goblin.Float)
```

At run time, I need to iterate thrown each one of the properties and be able to determine its class type (keyProperty or goblin.Property) I also need to be able to determine if the value is a string, integer, etc...

During instantiation, I create an airport object and set the values as following:

```
lhr = Airport()
lhr.airport_code = 'LHR'
print (lhr.airport_code.__class__.mro())
lhr.airport_city = 'London'
lhr.airport_name = 'London Heathrow International Airport'
lhr.airport_region = 'UK-EN'
lhr.airport_runways = 3
lhr.airport_longest_runway = 12395
lhr.airport_elev = 1026
lhr.airport_country = 'UK'
lhr.airport_lat = 33.6366996765137
lhr.airport_long = -84.4281005859375
```

However when I inspect the object while debugging it, all I get is the property name, defined as string and values, defined as string, integer, etc...  How can I check for the object type for each property? 
Any help or suggestions on how to handle this ?

Comment: What about type built-in function: type(1) == int returns True, type(instance) returns the class

Comment: Hi Eric, I tried. I can get all properties in a dictionary under the instance, and access the key (airport_code) and value (LHR) using key, values from the dictionary. But if I try to do type(key), it returns the type as a str.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimum working example? Define a simple class and show what you mean.

Comment: If, as seems likely, `goblin.Property` is a descriptor type, then it will be hard to access it directly. That's because a descriptor can change how Python does a lookup of it in another object. I suspect your `obj.__class__.__dict__` approach is the only real option.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was looking for. I had to call element.**class**.**dict**.items(): and I can get a dictionary with all the properties, mappings, etc...